# Android DataBinding expression with Listener Bindings

Tags: android, mvp, android-databinding

I'm using Android Data Binding library in the app which follows the [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) pattern. In the [talk](https://realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/) by George Mount and Yigit Boyar there is following example of expression used with the event handler:

```
<Button android:onClick="@{isAdult ? handlers.adultClick : handlers.childClick}" …/>
```

Is there any way to have the same functionality (i.e. different "onClick" event depending on a condition) not with [method references](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#method_references) but with [listener bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#listener_bindings) instead? Or maybe my approach is completely wrong and the logic should be moved to the presenter?

Comment: You can pass the condition to you `onClick` method and then operate depending on it, like `() -> handler.conditionClick(condition)`, and in your handler `void conditionClick(bool isTrue){ }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [listener_bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#listener_bindings)

If you need to use an expression with a predicate (e.g. ternary), you can use void as a symbol.

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> v.isVisible() ? doSomething() : void}"
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: what do you mean?<Button android:onClick="@{(v) -> isAdult ? null : presenter.onClick(v, viewModel)}" …/>

Comment: Ok, the answer is clear after editing, thank you! In my case it looks like this: android:onClick="@{() -> pesenter.someValue != null ? null : presenter.someMethodCall()}", I'm accepting this as a correct one.